# Error with visit root_path in cucumber specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

In my cucumber step definition file i have the following :

```
Given(/^I am on the home page$/) do
  visit root_path
end
```

But when i run the specs im getting the following error for the above

```
Given I am on the home page           # features/step_definitions/select_country_webpublisher_and_targettype_steps.rb:1
      Mysql2::Error: Table 'geomapping_tool_test.countrycode' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `CountryCode` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
      ./app/controllers/geo_mapping_controller.rb:3:in `index'
      ./features/step_definitions/select_country_webpublisher_and_targettype_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on the home page$/'
      features/select_country_webpublisher_and_targettype.feature:7:in `Given I am on the home page'
```

I have a model called CountryCode in my rails app that is connecting to a legacy database having a table with the same name, so in the model i have `self.table_name = 'CountryCode'`, is that affecting the test ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you "prepared" your test database?

`rake db:test:prepare`